# 301 redirects django redirect_to multiple redirects

Tags: django, redirect

I am back for advice. I have a site that needs SEO help and have been asked to ad a 301 redirect. This site is a convertion to django from php I gather. Now I have been given a csv of about 700 URL's all basically of

http://www.rhodeislandrow.com/floor-plans/search/?sort=price_desc&floor=---&max_price=1304&min_price=0&csrfmiddlewaretoken=3688d94aa3454e592f016d032a126328&availability=1322629596

Well I decided after research that I needed to do a from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to work around. But playing with this, it's not working. Can any one help me with a pointer on what to use? I have read the docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

and here are my URL's:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
from main.sitemaps import sitemaps
from main.views import *
admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Redirects from old site
    (r'^floor-plans/search/$', redirect_to, {'url': 'http://www.rhodeislandrow.com/floor-plans/'}),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^subscribe/$', SubscribeView, name='subscribe'),
    url(r'^vaultware-template/$', VaultwareTemplateView.as_view()),

    url(r'^', include('stateful.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    (r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    (r'^robots.txt$', include('robots.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Why not use the [redirect app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/?from=olddocs/) in `django.contrib`? You could write a script to process the CSV and create a new redirect. [I wrote a blog post that might help a little bit](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/2012/06/27/automatically-update-redirects-when-slug-changes/) (it shows how to automaticaly create redirects when changing a field, but it could be adapted)

Comment: Not working? What doesn't work? Exceptions? And what Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain enough. The redirect url 
(r'^floor-plans/search/$', redirect_to, {'url': 'http://www.rhodeislandrow.com/floor-plans/'}),
is not working. I am using Django 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Because my URL's are not ending in /search/ I needed to add the wildcard

```
(r'^floor-plans/search/.*$', redirect_to, {'url': 'http://www.rhodeislandrow.com/floor-plans/'}),
```

Thanks for the responses and I will use the **redirect app** for future projects.

Comment: Are these 301 redirects? (do they pass along SEO juice)